# SSRS Subscriptions use cached data

Tags: reporting-services

Currently we have all our users sign up for subscriptions (almost all at 8AM daily) to each report they need and currently we do not have caching enabled on the reports.  Is it safe to say when each subscription runs it's a full DB lookup and report generation?  If we enable Caching for say 30 minutes would that reduce DB workloads?

Comment: Read this: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1919/how-to-enable-caching-in-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the individual report is going to run the query and generate the report every time. If you had one subscription sending to multiple people, it would only occur once. Sounds like caching would be a good idea.

Comment: After looking at all my report subscriptions I took the your advice and just combined all the emails into one subscription.